# Capture USB signal from device and emulate it later

Tags: usb

I am creating a DIY system that uses various USB devices/sensors. Is there some software or hardware that is capable of recording the signal that is sent to the computer by the USB device so that I can emulate/re-send that exact same signal at a later time?

(Edited the question to to focus on the actual question I want answered.)

Comment: If it’s a DIY system, then add it into your own code. At the point where you receive USB input in real life, add two options, one to save it to a file & one to use that file for input, instead of real USB devices. Read up on Handed Abstraction. It should be fairly trivial to implement. Great question, btw.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, but that doesn't answer the question I'm asking. I just want to know if there is a way to record USB data coming into my computer so I can re-send the same data to my computer later.

Comment: Yes, I realize that - and I marked your question as a favourite, because I would be very interbred if such a thing exists. Just by coincidence, I was chatting over lunch abut PCOs - Poin of Control and observation (see [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Q4j0BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=pco+point+of+control+and+observation&source=bl&ots=U2VE1qCUF9&sig=ACfU3U0A36US0T6FI1aJ0x10qBOVyFQEjg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4xOWz8ITjAhUlVBUIHefFCl8Q6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=pco%20point%20of%20control%20and%20observation&f=false) --->

Comment: and [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=0nB6ZxfLmQoC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=pco+point+of+control+and+observation&source=bl&ots=XlXL-HzeII&sig=ACfU3U0HQx8RO2t3po8PUOUoU2JkA7wHag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4xOWz8ITjAhUlVBUIHefFCl8Q6AEwBXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=yILbBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA365&lpg=PA365&dq=pco+point+of+control+and+observation&source=bl&ots=rJixrsUazd&sig=ACfU3U0WWJxdBVKQxxSNs18U-V77ajoCjw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4xOWz8ITjAhUlVBUIHefFCl8Q6AEwCXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false). I think you will end up adding them at your Abstraction Layer ->

Comment: -> but that will give you more control, if you ever do want more than just feedback. It also lets you generate input from other programs, rather than just record/playback, although that is a good first step, if it exists. A great question !

Comment: I must rush a to a meeting, but just want to say that searching  for "`wireshark for USB`" gave some interesting results. [This](https://geekthis.net/post/usb-sniffing-and-programming/) for instance. Please let us know what you discover.